# Umbraco CMS on 1and1 shared server - Could not save the web.config file

Tags: iis, permissions, ftp, umbraco, shared-hosting

I have installed the files for Umbraco 4.0.4.2 (because 1and1 has problems with newer version, typical crap).

However when I load this domain http://s399064010.websitehome.co.uk and try to get past step 2 is gives me this error:

Could not save the web.config file. Please modify the connection string manually. Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

So I need some help please with someone who doesn't just repeat the same stuff found on Google or about the IIS because 1and1 is shared not dedicated so there is no windows interface. Has anyone gotten Umbraco to work on 1and1 and/or how can I do this/give permissions to the file (although I've tried giving it to all files and folders through both FileZilla FTP and 1and1 Webfiles browser.

Thanks guys and gals, Giles

Comment: Hope you have given the permissions for all the required folders?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this for the lifetime of your site, but to get through the set up try uploading the web.config with the [trust policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493%28VS.90%29.aspx) level specified as `Full`:

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

Reduce the trust level once you're up and running.

You could also just try with `Medium`, I'm not certain pre-4.5 versions have the following configuration property but if it is present also set `umbracoUseMediumTrust` to `true` too:

```
<add key="umbracoUseMediumTrust" value="true" />
```